# Regex for splitting apparel sizes

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have the following input (only for example, real input contains much more crazy data)

```
$values = [
    '32/34, 36/38, 40/42, 44/46',
    '40/42/44/46/48',
    '58/60',
    '39-42',
    '40-50-60',
    '24-25,26,28,30',
    '36 40,5 44',
];
```

and want to split it by separators like `/` or `,` but keep pairs of values. This should be done only, if separator does not occur multiple times, so the result should look like:

```
'32/34, 36/38, 40/42, 44/46'
    => [ '32/34', '36/38', '40/42', '44/46' ]
'40/42/44/46/48'
    => [ '40', '42', '44', '46', '48' ]
'58/60'
    => [ '58/60' ]
'39-42'
    => [ '39-42' ]
'40-50-60'
    => [ '40', '50', '60' ]
'24-25,26,28,30'
    => [ '24-25', '26', '28', '30' ]
'36 40,5 44'
    => [ '36', '40,5', '44' ]
```

What I have so far is

```
$separator = '^|$|[\s,\/-]';
$decimals = '\d+(?:[,.][05])?';
foreach ($values as $value) {
    preg_match_all('/' .
        '(?<=' . $separator . ')' .
        '(?:' .
            '(?P<var1>(' . $decimals . ')[\/-](?-1)|(?-1))' .
        ')(?=' . $separator . ')' .
    '/ui', $value, $matches);
    print_r($matches);
}
```

But this fails for `40/42/44/46/48` which returns

```
[var1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 40/42
        [1] => 44/46
        [2] => 48
    )
```

But each number should be returned separately. Modifying regex to `'(?P<var1>(' . $decimals . ')([\/-])(?-2)|(?-2))(?!\3)'` is better, but still returns wrong result

```
[var1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 40
        [1] => 42
        [2] => 44
        [3] => 46/48
    )
```

How should the correct regex look like?

Comment: Maybe just parse it as a CSV first, then preg_split on `-` or `/`.

Comment: @user3783243 As my regex becomes really complex because of the mixed input data, CSV is not an option

Comment: Well I used this [looooooong](https://regex101.com/r/hRtlEq/1) logic but it might fail for your crazy data.

Comment: @Rahul have you seen that `40/42` from second value is captured in a single group falsely?

Comment: Yes. It's not an exact solution. Just an idea for regex. I am sure there is more efficient way using programming.

Comment: Someone feel free to correct me, but I don't believe the behavior you're describing in this problem can be defined by a regular grammar; I think this problem is beyond the scope of pure regex. I'd recommend parsing it, because this data is just wildly variable.

Comment: You are absolutely right, but I don't expect a 100% match. I've modified my regex a bit and replaced lookbehind with negative lookahead (as PHP supports fixed length lookbehind only). And it seems to work in most of my cases: https://regex101.com/r/q3YSa7/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in comments above, I know that a 100% match is not possible, because of user input. But I've found a regex which fits most of my use cases:

```
(?<=^|$|[\s,\/-])(?:(?P<var1>(?<![\/-])(?!(?:(\d+(?:[,.][05])?)[\/-]){2}(?-1))(\d+(?:[,.][05])?)[\/-](?-1)|(?-1)))(?=^|$|[\s,\/-])
```

See https://regex101.com/r/q3YSa7/1